# Problemas em configurar Composer com XAMPP em ambiente Windows

Tags: php, composer

A instalação do composer no windows tem me dado algum trabalho.
Tenho umas dúvidas:

O instalador do Composer no Windows pede para informar o local do `php.exe`, e se instala ali.
Após isso rodei os comandos no console meu `composer.json` está assim:

```
{
    "require": {
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.2"
    }
}
```

O `composer.Lock` e o `autoload.php` foram criados após a instalação tudo correto.
Na hora de utilizar no meu arquivo se eu indicar :

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

Não vai funcionar pois a pasta vendor está em `C:\XAMPP\PHP` e o projeto em `C:\XAMPP\HTDOCS\Site`.

Eu tentei indicar no require o caminho completo do vendor (`C:\XAMPP\PHP\Vendor\autoload.php`) não funcionou também.

Alguém sabe onde estou errando? Se é de outra forma que informa onde está o autoload?

Comment: Já tentou colocar o diretório onde estão o composer e o PHP na sua variável de ambiente `PATH`? Assim você pode chamá-los de qualquer lugar.

Comment: O arquivo `composer.json` deve está na pasta raiz do seu projeto (C:\XAMPP\HTDOCS\Site)

Comment: @luciorubenns Então acho que tem algo errado,pois passei os arquivos para lá e mesmo assim não funcionou

Comment: Ao rodar `composer update` na pasta do projeto, qual a saída?

Comment: @luciorubeens Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files

Comment: A pasta `vendor` e o arquivo `composer.lock` também foram gerados na pasta do projeto?

Comment: @luciorubeens Positivo

Comment: @RodolfoOliveira Como mencionaram, você sempre deve usar composer install/update na pasta do seu projeto, assim como o arquivo composer.json deve estar lá também. E como está conseguiu utilizar o composer e autoload?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você está confundindo as coisas.

O Composer é um gerenciador de pacotes a nível de projeto. Você não irá criar um arquivo `composer.json` na sua pasta do PHP, mas sim na pasta de cada projeto:

Diretório do projeto antes do `composer install` / `update`:

[image: Diretório antes do composer install]

Ao executar o comando em nosso terminal, o composer baixará as dependências ...

[image: composer update console]

... e irá criar as pasta `vendor` junto com as dependências do seu `composer.json`

[image: Pastas do Projeto]

Agora sim, inclua o `vendor/autoload.php` para usar as dependências do seu projeto. Lembre-se que o caminho é **relativo** a **raiz do seu projeto**.

index.php

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use GuzzleHttp\Client;    
$client = new Client();
```

Comment: Perfeito. O ponto é exatamente esse: as dependências são a nível de projeto, então os arquivos `composer.json` e `composer.lock` devem ser versionados junto com seu projeto.

Comment: É possível usar dependências a nível global (phpunit, phpspec)  para utilizar via linha de comando, mas isso já é outro assunto.

Comment: Obrigad.Eu nunca tinha usado o composer o que faltava era o "use GuzzleHttp\Client"

Comment: @RodolfoOliveira esse use é para informar que quando você for usar uma classe `Client` ele busque no namespace `GuzzleHttp`. Outra forma seria usar o caminho completo `new GuzzleHttp\Client`, porém isso pode se tornar repetitivo.